# How to replace the search submit button with a Font Awesome character?

Tags: 8, search, forms

I would like to replace the search submit button with a *Font Awesome* character like the *Magnifier (Search Icon)* character, and put *Search the site* inside the search box.

How can I achieve something like this?

> [image]

Comment: You need to add more than a one-line question, and add more than the question title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to add the new form button, I used [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x) in my template.theme file in my theme folder (Notice:replace ThemeName with the name of your theme in below code):

**ThemeName.theme:**

```
**
 * Replace the Search Submit Button with a Font Awesome Character.
 */
function ThemeName_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search');
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = html_entity_decode('&#xf002;');
  $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-button';
}
```

Remeber use `html_entity_decode()` to parse the Unicode code.
and CSS:

```
.search-button input[type="submit"]{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #fff !important;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. To convert the label to a placeholder text, you need to use `hook_form_alter` in your custom theme in Drupal. The form id for the search box is `seach_block_form`, so you can use the following code to do this:

   ```
   /**
    * Implements hook_form_alter().
    */
   function hook_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
     $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search');
   }
   ```
2. To change the look and feel of the search button, you can simply use CSS. What I usually do is to set the background to an the icon and use text-indent to hide the text.

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani In the `.theme` file. Remember to change the `hook` to your theme name.

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani It should be fairly simple with CSS to get what you want. All you need is an image of the search icon, rest is just a matter of color, placement etc

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani Any more help would mean that I would do it all for you

Answer (score 4):

I've done the following in a preprocess function to add font-awesome icons. It's a bit difficult with the search input because the only thing that identifies the search button is the label. Then hide the element with the selector `.button--text` in CSS.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_input(&$variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];
  // Ugh :(
  if ($element['#type'] === 'submit' && $element['#value']->__toString() === 'Search') {
    $variables['children'] = $element['#children'];
    $variables['children'][] = [
      '#theme' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'i',
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['fa', 'fa-search']],
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question so that there are details about "cant get any result". This is too broad of a statement to answer. Are there any error messages? Did you rebuild cache? What's your template like? What's the markup?

Comment: I add above code to my theme file and change the "MYTHEME" to real theme name, I rebuild cache for several times, but yet search submit button not changed.

Answer (score 1):

**Instructions for Drupal 8 / FontAwesome 5**

Create a YOUR_THEME_NAME_HERE.THEME file and place it in your themes directory (ie. your_site_name/themes/your_theme_name)

Paste this into the file, it is PHP code to find the Search Block and change the value to the UNICODE for the FontAwesome icon. You can find other characters at this link https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet.

```
<?php
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_HERE_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search');
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = html_entity_decode('&#xf002;');
}
?>
```

Open the CSS file of your theme (ie. your_site_name/themes/your_theme_name/css/styles.css) and then paste this in which will change all input submit text to FontAwesome. Not sure if this will work if you also want to add text in the input button though for just an icon it is fine.

Make sure you import FontAwesome, add this at the top of the CSS file

```
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css');
```

then add this in the CSS

```
input#edit-submit {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;  
}
```

**FLUSH ALL CACHES AND IT SHOULD WORK FINE**

***Add Google Font Effects***

If you are using Google Web Fonts as well you can add also add effects to the icon (see more here https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#enabling_font_effects_beta). You need to import a Google Web Font including the effect(s) you would like to use first in the CSS so it will be

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800&effect=3d-float');
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css');
```

Then go back to your .THEME file and add the class for the 3D Float Effect so the code will now add a class to the input. There are different effects available. So just choose the effect you like, change the CSS for the font import and the change the value FONT-EFFECT-3D-FLOAT int the code below to font-effect-WHATEVER_EFFECT_HERE. Not effects are still in Beta and don't work in all browsers so read here before you try it https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#enabling_font_effects_beta

```
<?php
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_HERE_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search');
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = html_entity_decode('&#xf002;');
  $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'font-effect-3d-float';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Drupal 8 / FontAwesome 5**  (other similar solutions above did not work)

If you have the [fontawesome](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome) module already installed you can add to your `THEMENAME.theme` file

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

function THEMENAME_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search');
    $value = new FormattableMarkup('<i class="fas fa-search"></i>@text', ['@text' => '',]);
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes must be made in the yourtheme.theme file in your yourtheme directory. The following changes the submit button text.

```
function yourtheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Zoeken');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use boostrap subtheme and drupal you can remove glyphicon in settings theme for all buttons BUT you can remove glyphicon for specific button with this hook in your TEMPLATE.theme 
https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/bootstrap.api.php/function/hook_bootstrap_iconize_text_alter/7

```
function YOURTEMPLATENAME_bootstrap_iconize_text_alter(array &$texts) {
  // use ksm($form) OR other dump($form) functions
  if($texts['contains']['YOURTEXT']) {
    unset($texts['contains']['YOURTEXT']);
  }
}
```

if you want to show the title of the button, you must copy the file bootstrap/src/Plugin/Form/SearchForm.php into your SUBTHEME

YOURSUBTHEME/src/Plugin/Form/SearchForm.php
copy and paste the content of the file into your file and edit the content like that :

```
<?php
...
use Drupal\bootstrap\Plugin\Form\FormBase;
...

  public function alterFormElement(Element $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
    $form->advanced->setProperty('collapsible', TRUE);
    $form->advanced->setProperty('collapsed', TRUE);
    $form->basic->removeClass('container-inline');
    $form->basic->submit->setProperty('icon_only', FALSE);
    $form->basic->keys->setProperty('input_group_button', TRUE);
  }
}
```

with this you will see the text "search" only and no glyphicon on your search button

don't forget to flush the cache !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside a twig template `YOURTHEME/templates/input/input--button.html.twig`

Add this above the lines where `<button>` is rendered:

```
{# replace Glyphicon with FontAwesome for Search #}
{% if icon and icon['#attributes']['class']|join matches '/search/' %}
  {% set icon = {
    '#type': 'html_tag',
    '#tag': 'i',
    '#attributes': {
      'class': [
        'fa', 'fa-search'
      ],
      'aria-hidden': 'true'
    },
  } %}
{% endif %}
```

It will replace the default `icon` object, adding an `<i>` tag with FontAwesome CSS classes.

You can check the `icon` object defaults using `dump`:

```
{{ dump(icon) }}
```