# How to change search placeholder?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks, search

So far I have tried this code in mytheme.theme:

```
function mytheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Custom wording');
}
```

And this one:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') { 
    $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Custom wording');
  }
}
```

Also this one:

```
function mytheme_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
    $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Custom wording');
}
```

Site is not crashing, but nothing happens on the placeholder.

I have based these 3 snippets on these pages:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.5.x
- [How to replace the search submit button with a Font Awesome character?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197439/how-to-replace-the-search-submit-button-with-a-font-awesome-character)