# How can I use material symbols in the search bar submit input?

Tags: theming, 10

## Background

I have a Drupal 10 site with a search bar that appears on the front page. Using this search bar redirects the user to a search page with a similar search bar, underneath which are the results. By default, both of these search bars just have the word "search".

I added the material-icons module and have successfully used material symbols on other parts of the site, but I do not know how to do this with the submit input in the search bar.

I found a [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197439/how-to-replace-the-search-submit-button-with-a-font-awesome-character) where the user added a fontawesome icon, and the solution (to use unicode) is not applicable for me.

## Attempts

### Attempt 1

I had a partially successful attempt by creating a module with a function that alters the search form:

```
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

function search_bar_icon_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Set a placeholder for the search input
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search');
  
  // Replace the submit button with a Material Icon
  $icon_html = '<span class="material-symbols-rounded">search</span>';
  $form['actions']['submit']['#markup'] = Markup::create($icon_html);
  
  // Optionally, you can hide the original submit button text
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = '';
}
```

This solution is not ideal because html input does not allow children, so instead, it places the span as the input's sibling. This requires CSS to pad the empty input and translate the  sibling over the empty button. This solution feels messy and overly complicated, so I wanted to explore better options before I go with this.

### Attempt 2

I attempted to create a twig template in my custom theme to override the way that the search bar is being generated. To do this, I went into the `core/modules/search/templates`
to locate the default template, however there was only one template named `search-result.html.twig` which renders single search results, not the search bar itself. I cannot find the correct default twig template so I don't know what to name my custom one to override the styling.

My goal with this attempt is to replace the input with a button that can hold an icon if possible.

## Summary

I feel like adding an icon shouldn't be so complicated and I must be missing something obvious. What is the best way to theme my search bar so that it shows a material symbols magnifying glass instead of the word "search"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this in a relatively simple way.

This answer presumes you are using the [Material Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/material_icons) module, although I configured this module to use Rounded Material Symbols instead. I also created a custom module and `form_search_block_form_alter` to alter the search block form and add in this icon.

### Custom Module

The form alter code is housed in a custom module comprised simply of an `info.yml` file, and the `.module` file containing the code.

```
.
└── web/
    └── modules/
        └── custom/
            └── search_bar_icon/
                ├── search_bar_icon.info.yml
                └── search_bar_icon.module
```

Once the module is created, make sure you install it in the Extend menu.

### Form Alter

In order for an element to use a Material Symbol, it must be assigned a `material-symbols` class, and the content of the element must be the name of the required icon. In my case the search `form-submit` button already had "search" as the content, which is the name of the material symbol I wanted to use, so all I had to do was add the `material-symbols-rounded` class to this button.

```php
<?php
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

function search_bar_icon_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Set a placeholder for the search input
  $form['keys']['#attributes']['placeholder'][] = t('Search');

  // Add a class to the submit button
  $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'material-symbols-rounded';
}
```

This resulted in the "search" text being replaced by the Material Symbols magnifying glass.