# Allow html tags in Form submit button in block plugin

Tags: forms, 8, blocks, plugins

I'm using a block plugin to render a user specified form. I'm retrieving the form like so:

```
public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $this->configuration['template'] = $form_state->getValue('template');
    $selected_entity_type_bundle     = $form_state->getValue('entity_type');
    $values                          = explode('.', $selected_entity_type_bundle);

    $this->configuration['entity_type']             = $values[0];
    $this->configuration['bundle']                  = $values[1];
    $this->configuration['entity_type_submit_text'] = $form_state->getValue('entity_type_submit_text');

}

private function buildEntityForm() {
    $values = array();
    // Specify selected bundle if the entity has bundles.
    if (\Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinition($this->configuration['entity_type'])->hasKey('bundle')) {
        $bundle_key = \Drupal::entityManager()->getDefinition($this->configuration['entity_type'])->getKey('bundle');
        $values     = array($bundle_key => $this->configuration['bundle']);
    }
    $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()
        ->getStorage($this->configuration['entity_type'])
        ->create($values);

    if ($entity instanceof EntityOwnerInterface) {
        $entity->setOwnerId(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    }

    $form = \Drupal::entityManager()
        ->getFormObject($this->configuration['entity_type'], 'default')
        ->setEntity($entity);

    return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
}
```

This grabs the form just fine, and I render it using

```
public function build() {

    if ($this->configuration['entity_type'] != '') {
        $entityForm                                = $this->buildEntityForm();
        $entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t($this->configuration['entity_type_submit_text']);// Editable submit button value.
        if ($this->configuration['template'] == 'learnmore') {
            $entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'] = '<i class="fa fa-mail"></i>'.$entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'];
        }
    } else {
        $entityForm = '';
    }
    $entityForm['actions']['preview'] = '';

    $content = [
        'template'     => [
            '#type'       => 'container',
            '#attributes' => [
                'class'      => [$this->configuration['template']],
            ],
            'header'  => [
                '#type'  => 'html_tag',
                '#tag'   => 'h5',
                '#value' => $this->configuration['label'],
            ],
            'form' => $entityForm,
        ],
    ];

    return $content;
}
```

Which renders the form. But I'm setting the submit button text as specified by the user like so

```
$entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t($this->configuration['entity_type_submit_text']);
```

And I want to add an icon inside the button before the text like so

```
$entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'] = '<i class="fa fa-mail"></i>'.$entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'];
```

The issue is when it renders the button it includes the html tags so the actual submit button text is

> `<i class="fa fa-mail"></i>`Submit Button Text

It displays the html tags instead of rendering the actual icon. 
Is there a way to allow html tags inside of a submit button on a form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Font Awesome on a Drupal form submit button?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77116/how-do-i-use-font-awesome-on-a-drupal-form-submit-button)

Comment: Additionally not listed in an answer there, but submit/button elements exposed the `input__submit` theme_wrapper, which I believe is targetable in a template preprocess or template itself for adding custom markup and/or attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a formattable markup:

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

  $value = new FormattableMarkup('<i class="fa fa-mail"></i>@text', [
    '@text' => $value,
  ]);
```

The formattable string will not be escaped. The variable in the placeholder `@text` will be escaped and that is important, because it contains user input.

Comment: I tried    $entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t($this->configuration['entity_type_submit_text']);// Editable submit button value.
   if ($this->configuration['template'] == 'learnmore') {
    $icon = new FormattableMarkup('<i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>@text', ['@text' => $icon]);

    $entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'] = $icon.$entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'];

   } but it did not escape the icon

Comment: This is a bit easier to read http://pastie.org/private/n5zjrnu08y5acfil3whuqg

Comment: I realized that it might not be possible since it's inserting the html into the 'value' attribute of the submit input tag. Which I don't believe supports html.

Comment: This is also not a good solution and angry Danish people will bring their wrath upon you for putting markup in code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible since it's inserting the html into the value attributes of a submit type input tag rather than in the content within a button tag. To resolve this I appended a button element like so.

```
    $content = [
        'template'     => [
            '#type'       => 'container',
            '#attributes' => [
                'class'      => [$this->configuration['template']],
            ],
            'header'  => [
                '#type'  => 'html_tag',
                '#tag'   => 'h5',
                '#value' => $this->configuration['label'],
            ],
            'form' => $entityForm,
        ],
    ];
    if ($this->configuration['template'] == 'learnmore') {
        $content['template'][] = [
            'test'           => [
                '#type'         => 'html_tag',
                '#tag'          => 'button',
                '#value'        => '<i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> '.$entityForm['actions']['submit']['#value'],
                '#allowed_tags' => 'i',
                '#attributes'   => [
                    'type'         => 'submit',
                    'form'         => 'contact-message-learn-more-form',
                ],
            ],
        ];

    }

    return $content;
```